# Explanation of single and double slit diffraction, and Frensel diffraction in light of Feynman's method of probability amplitudes

Tags: diffraction

In his [second lecture](https://youtu.be/kMSgE62S6oo) of the QED series, Prof. Richard Feynman explains the phenomenon of reflection from a plane mirror, and then the working of a diffraction grating with his theory of arrows (probability amplitudes), and we see that how the new theory, which is much moved from the real world, clearly explains the two phenomena.

But Prof. Feynman does not go into the explanation of other optical phenomena like single and double slit diffraction, though he slightly mentions the single slit diffraction at one point. He says that many of the audience might not know what these phenomena are, and hence, he doesn't complicate his lecture unnecessarily.

I want to have a clear explanation of single slit, double slit and Frensel diffraction in this theory, that is, in terms of probability amplitudes and like the way Prof. Feynman explains the other two phenomena. Can anyone give a proper explanation in light of this theory?

Comment: Phasors are a classic. You can find this in any book about physical optics.

Comment: I've seen Resnick and Halliday, but didn't find it there. Can you refer any book?

Comment: See this answer of mine: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253449/109928

Comment: It was in Halliday & Resnick 1990: http://www.lepla.edu.pl/en/modules/Activities/m14/m14-theo.htm

Comment: @Pieter Really interesting. My book is a newer version, so sadly this has been removed.

Comment: *"I've seen Resnick and Halliday"* Well, that's a general introductory text, not "a book about physical optics", though the editions I've seen have a chapter on wave optics which had a introductory treatment.

Comment: @dmckee I don't have a specific book on physical optics, other than a general one like Halliday. Can you refer some good book? Or should I post a separate resource-recommendations question on that?